# Rails -How to get(query) the all child record in including parent record in single recursive table Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have table say users .which is recursive means there is filed parent_id in the table which is the user id of any of the user of same table.table structure is someting like that:

```
id  email         parent_id
1   test@test.com   nil
2   test1@test.com  1
3   email           1
4   email           2
5   email          nil
6   email           3
```

now i want if i have to query all the child record including parent using any one id .how can i do that in rails  .I want to recursively get all the child record including parent record.

Comment: What DB you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with

```
def find_all_child_parents(p_id)
  return_childs = []
  # Add this node.
  return_childs << Child.find(p_id)
  direct_childs = User.where(parent_id: p_id) 
  direct_child.each do |child|
    # Add nodes you get from recursive call
    return_childs.concat(find_all_child_parents(child.id))
  end
  return_childs 
end
```

It gives you recursivly all the childs to a parent, including the parent itself.